# Prevent Kafka JDBC Sink from recording __connect_partition and __connect_offset

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I've got a log compacted topic in Kafka that is being written to Postgres via a JDBC sink connector. Though I've got `mode=upsert` set on the connector, it still adds a unique row in the sink database for each value because it's recording the topic offset (`__connect_offset`) and partition (`__connect_partition`) to each row along with the data.

How do I disable the JDBC Sink Connector from recording the topic information (which I don't care about)? Adding a `fields.whitelist` that grabs only my data columns did not succeed in preventing this metadata from creeping into my database.

An SMT like the following also does not work:

```
"transforms": "blacklist",
"transforms.blacklist.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
"transforms.blacklist.blacklist": "__connect_partition, __connect_offset"
```

Answer (score 2):

My bad... I had misconfigured my primary key on the connector. I thought that I was correctly telling it to convert the topic key into the table primary key. In the end, the following connector configuration worked:

```
"pk.mode": "record_key",
"pk.fields": "[Key column name here]"
```